# awk to replace columns and print if condition statisfy

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with below output

```
Sending showtrans  string ...

Oldest redo log files necessary to restart Extract are:

Redo Thread 1, Redo Log Sequence Number 29334, SCN 3364.4078507030 (14452348490774), RBA 673593872
Redo Thread 2, Redo Log Sequence Number 12371, SCN 3365.484854852 (14453049805892), RBA 3443216

XID         Items    Extract   Redo Thread  Start Time           SCN                               Redo Seq  Redo RBA            Status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
75.2.549177 0        sting1  1            2015-12-23:07:26:47  3364.4078507030 (14452348490774)  29334     673593872           Running
126.6.3078970        sting2  1            2015-12-24:00:22:11  3365.308496723 (14452873447763)   29364     6462055952          Running
```

I need the output as:

```
75.2 sting1

126.6 sting2
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: cat long_trans.txt |sed -ne '/^----/{s///; :a' -e 'n;p;ba' -e '}'| grep -v ^$ | awk '{print $1,$2}' | awk -F "." '{print $1"."$2,$3}' | awk '{print $1,$3}' | sort -u

Comment: In the first line, string1 is in the third column, in the second sting2 is in the second column, is that correct?

Comment: yes that is the main issue

Comment: Therefore column "Items" may be empty?

Comment: 50.10 E6D6ERR
50.10 E6D6LGDA
50.10 E6D6MAIN
50.10 E6D6SEQ
619.25 E6D6ARGL
75.2 0
i need the first two digits and E* in the second column

Comment: column item wont be empty but  in the XID column total no of digits will differ ex :126.6.3078970  here last 0 is of item ex 2:75.2.549177 0 here there is space which is coming before the item value due to which output is wrong

Comment: Please update your question when adding new information.

Comment: Is this because column width is fixed and it's wrapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk '{split($1,a,".");if(a[1]!="") if(a[1]+0==a[1]){printf "%d.%d %s\n", a[1], a[2], ($2+0==$2)?$3:$2}}' input.txt
```

This will check when the second column is missing, so it gets the appropriated column.

Comment: Awesome. thnz a lot its working fine

Comment: one doubt. if the item column value is not equal to 0 then also it will work as above right

Comment: Yep, that testing is just a trick to make sure that the field is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat more than one space as a field separator, and a single one as a part of data:

```
awk -F'  +|[.]' '$1~"^[0-9]+"{print $1"."$2,$4}' file
```

Output:

```
75.2 sting1
126.6 sting2
```

Comment: this also working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not `awk` - but you already have `awk` answers, and so I offer an alternative approach.

I would probably do it like this:

```
perl -lne 'print "$1 $2" if m/^(\d+\.\d+)[^a-z]*(\w+)/' long_trans.txt
```

We apply a pattern match, if it does match, we print what it captured:

```
^          # start of line
(\d+\.\d+) # digits seperated by a literal . (capturing)
[^a-z]     # anything that isn't [a-z]
(\w+)      # word characters (alphanumerics mostly) (capturing)
```